# Store io.vavr.collection.Map into MongoDB with Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, vavr

I have problem with serialization and deserialization vavr Map into the MongoDB with the Spring Data.

The code

```
public class Location {
    public final Map<String, String> region;        
    public Location() {
        this.region = HashMap.of("City", "Warsaw", "Country", "Poland");
    }
}

public interface LocationRepository extends CrudRepository<Location, String> {
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class VavrMapMongoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(VavrMapMongoApplication.class, args);
    }       
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner importData(LocationRepository repository) {
        return (String... args) -> {
            final Location location = new Location();
            repository.save(location);
        };
    }
}
```

gives me an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.vavr.collection.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.util.Map (io.vavr.collection.HashMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.Map is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:582) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:550) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:526) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
```

I've solved it with `@WritingConverter` and `@ReadingConverter`:

```
@Configuration
public class VavrCustomConverter {
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(asList(new VavrMapToMapConverter(), new MapToVavrMapConverter()));
    }

    @WritingConverter
    private static class VavrMapToMapConverter implements Converter<Map, java.util.Map> {
        @Override
        public java.util.Map convert(Map map) {
            return map.toJavaMap();
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    private static class MapToVavrMapConverter implements Converter<java.util.Map, Map> {
        @Override
        public Map convert(java.util.Map map) {
            return HashMap.ofAll(map);
        }
    }
}
```

but it works only if `HashMap` contains java primitive types. When I change the code to:

```
public class Region {
    public final String country;
    public final String city;

    public Region(String country, String city) {
        this.country = country;
        this.city = city;
    }
}

public class Location {
    public final Map<String, Region> region;

    public Location(Map<String, Region> region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner importData(LocationRepository repository) {
    return (String... args) -> {
        final Region region = new Region("Poland", "Warsaw");
        final HashMap<String, Region> pl = HashMap.of("PL", region);
        final Location location = new Location(pl);
        repository.save(location);
}
```

I've got exception:

```
Caused by: org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class test.vavrmapmongo.Region.
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecCache.getOrThrow(CodecCache.java:46) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
    at org.bson.codecs.configuration.ProvidersCodecRegistry.get(ProvidersCodecRegistry.java:63) ~[bson-3.8.2.jar:na]
```

Why? `java.util.Map` is serialized pretty well to MongoDB with POJOs. I'm looking for generic way to do this with the vavr Map (not Document converter just for `Region` class).